# Pause and Resume Lottie Animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, lottie

I'm implementing a Lottie animation and the entire animation works great! However, I would like to add a bit of code that will pause the animation after 30 frames which I can then resume after a certain amount of time. Here is the code so far:

```
animationView.playAnimation(0, 30)
animationView.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
   override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
      if (isLoading == false) {
         //Everything has loaded. Continue Animation 
         
         //This line has no effect. The animation does not continue
         animationView.playAnimation(30, 60)
         //Resuming the animation just makes the animation disappear
         //animation.resume()
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 18):

What you can do is use **progress** from LottieAnimationView, threads and a flag, this will allow you to **pause** at a certain progress and **resume** exactly when you need to play your animation again.

I created the following example:

```
animationView.playAnimation()
animationView.loop(false)

isAnimating = true // Setup your flag

thread {
    while (isAnimating){ // Loop that checks the progress of your animation
        if (animationView.progress >= 0.5f){// If animation reaches 50%
            runOnUiThread {
                animationView.pauseAnimation()// Pause Animation
            }
            Thread.sleep(5000) // Pause for 5 seconds
            runOnUiThread {
                animationView.playAnimation(0.5f,1f) // Resume your animation from 50% to 100%
            }
            isAnimating = false
        }
        if(animationView.progress >= 1f){ // If animation reaches 100% stop animation
            runOnUiThread {
                animationView.cancelAnimation()
                isAnimating = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `animationView.loop(false)` is deprecated as on 2.8.0. What is the equivalent method?

Comment: @hkchakladar I'm using `animationDrawable.repeatCount = LottieDrawable.INFINITE` and `animationDrawable.repeatMode = LottieDrawable.RESTART`.

Comment: This is not life cycle aware method and it may cause memory leaks and null pointer exceptions

Answer (score 6):

```
animationView.setMinAndMaxProgress(0.0f, 0.5f);//set 50% animation //lottie version 2.7.0
```

Comment: Hi Mr.hir, welcome to stackoverflow, a handy tip going forward, some explanations about your answer would make your post much more valued and upvoted. =)

Comment: This works for me. Just add this line before calling `playAnimation()`

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        animationView.pauseAnimation();
    }
}, 8000); // after 8s animation will pause/stop/cancel/resume.
```